# How to get back to the latest commit after checking out a previous commit?

Tags: git, version-control

I sometimes check out some previous version of the code to examine or test.  I have seen instructions on what to do if I wish to modify previous commits -- but suppose I make no changes.  After I've done e.g. `git checkout HEAD^`, how do I get back to the tip of the branch?.. `git log` no longer shows me the SHA of the latest commit.

Comment: Regarding the `git log` sentence of your question, you can always run `git log --all` (or more usefully, `git log --oneline --graph --all`).

Comment: Expanding on @Wildcard s comment, you can create a wonderful alias out of that `git log` command: [git adog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/4742889)

Answer (score 904, accepted):

If you know the commit you want to return to is the head of some branch, or is tagged, then you can just

```
git checkout branchname
```

You can also use `git reflog` to see what other commits your HEAD (or any other ref) has pointed to in the past.

---

Edited to add:

In newer versions of Git, if you only ran `git checkout` or something else to move your `HEAD` once, you can also do

```
git checkout -
```

to switch back to wherever it was before the last checkout. This was motivated by the analogy to the shell idiom `cd -` to go back to whatever working directory one was previously in.

Comment: I'd like to mention that the typical example would be "git checkout master".  One of the difficulties I had learning to use git was not knowing what specific keywords (e.g. "master") I can actually substitute in for placeholder words like "branchname".

Comment: `master` isn't really any sort of keyword, the way `HEAD` is. It is just the default branch name in a new repository. You can run `git branch` to get a list of branches in your repository, and `git tag -l` for a list of tags. Similarly, `origin` is the default name of the remote that a repository is cloned from, but there's nothing special about it.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, `git reflog` gives you a list of hashes, at which point you can use `git checkout [commit-hash]`.

Comment: I deleted a file and tried the command, but it doesn't completely reset it. First of all, it's not recursive. Then when I try this on the file i deleted, git afterwards tells me that HEAD is detached. What to do?

Comment: @DanielS.: The question and my answer were about *commits*, while you're talking about files. Git treats them rather differently.

Comment: Found via reddit: https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html "A "choose your own adventure" on fixing git commits"

Comment: -1 this does not work. I did this: git checkout 9896ce318e4f4752812e7a5d6bdefaa430b290be .
git checkout And now have big issue

Comment: The `git checkout -` for the specific usecase of moving to latest commit may or may not work. E.g. if you did more than checkout in the row, it not going to work.

Comment: wow i learned two things, cd previous, and git checkout previous, yay hyphens

Comment: When you are in a 'detached HEAD' state, you can get back to the latest commit using `git switch -`.

Answer (score 47):

**git checkout master**

master is the tip, or the last commit.  **gitk** will only show you up to where you are in the tree at the time.  **git reflog** will show all the commits, but in this case, you just want the tip, so git checkout master.

Comment: This. Or `git checkout branchname`

Comment: Git has changed the default branch name from `master` to `main`. Thus, nowadays `git checkout main` will get you what you want

Comment: @codeananda Unless you're working in one of the _many_ repos that didn't change from `master`. In other words, you can't assume it will be one or the other (although I assume if you get it wrong, Git will tell you - I'm a primarily Mercurial user so I can't say for sure).

Answer (score 28):

Came across this question just now and have something to add

**To go to the most recent commit:**

```
git checkout $(git log --branches -1 --pretty=format:"%H")
```

**Explanation:**

`git log --branches` shows log of commits from all local branches
`-1` limit to one commit → most recent commit
`--pretty=format:"%H"` format to only show commit hash
`git checkout $(...)` use output of subshell as argument for checkout

**Note:**

This will result in a detached head though (because we checkout directly to the commit). This can be avoided by extracting the branch name using `sed`, explained below.

---

**To go to the branch of the most recent commit:**

```
git checkout $(git log --branches -1 --pretty=format:'%D' | sed 's/.*, //g')
```

**Explanation:**

`git log --branches` shows log of commits from all local branches
`-1` limit to one commit → most recent commit
`--pretty=format:"%D"` format to only show ref names
`| sed 's/.*, //g'` ignore all but the last of multiple refs (*)
`git checkout $(...)` use output of subshell as argument for checkout

**) HEAD and remote branches are listed first, local branches are listed last in alphabetically descending order, so the one remaining will be the alphabetically first branch name*

**Note:**

This will always only use the (alphabetically) first branch name if there are multiple for that commit.

---

Anyway, I think the best solution would just be to display the ref names for the most recent commit to know where to checkout to:

```
git log --branches -1 --pretty=format:'%D'
```

E.g. create the alias `git top` for that command.

Comment: Somehow I goofed up the second command... Fixed it, it will now correctly check you out ot the branch of the most recent commit.

Comment: Bash/zsh alias for the command to return back to head `alias git-head='git checkout $(git log --branches -1 --pretty=format:"%D" | sed "s/.*, //g")'`

Answer (score 10):

```
git reflog //find the hash of the commit that you want to checkout
git checkout <commit number>>
```

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the graphical GUI ... `gitk` it shows all commits. Sometimes it is easier to work graphical ... ^^

Comment: yes, this is actually how I've done it in the past -- but I don't have the GUI available at the moment

Answer (score 9):

You can use one of the following git command for this:

```
git checkout master
git checkout branchname
```

Answer (score 6):

If your latest commit is on the master branch, you can simply use

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 4):

show all branches and commit 
**git log --branches --oneline**

show last commit 
**git log --branches -1 --oneline**

show before last commit 
**git log --branches -2 --oneline**

Comment: Will the first command actually commit what code is currently staged, or am I misreading this?

Answer (score 2):

For `git` versions >=2.33.0

```
git switch -d -
```

allows you check out to the previously checked out commit. So, you can go back-and-forth by switching between two commits. Please notice that `-d` flag allows you to surf among commits in a detached state.

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: I forgot to add `-d` flag. I am correcting the answer. Thank you @HomeroEsmeraldo for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a branch different than master, one easy way is to check out that branch, then check out master.  Voila, you are back at the tip of master.   There's probably smarter ways...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `git pull origin branchname`. It will fetch the latest commit again.

Comment: I don't recommend this if you don't want to pull from upstream. One should handle merge conflicts only when they are ready to.

Comment: Well, in that case, the head will remain detached state even if you checkout to the latest commit.