# Get latest code after cheking out old commit?

Tags: git

I had several commits. I needed to push an old commit but not the newest ones. I used git checkout --hard on an old commit and pushed successfully.

Now I want to get all my work back that I havnt pushed. However I forgot to make a note of the last hash so I dont know what to checkout.

I cant see it with git log (the latest it shows is the commit that i checked out) and I cant see commits that havnt been pushed on github.

Accoring to this link I should be able to see these commits with 
git reflog, but the newest its showing me is the commit that I checked out. 
[How to get back to the latest commit after checking out a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427288/how-to-get-back-to-the-latest-commit-after-checking-out-a-previous-commit)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog):

```
git reflog
```

You will get the sha1 you had before the `git reset --hard`.

You can see an example in "[Undoing a `git reset --hard HEAD~1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21778/6309)"