# Losing more recent commits when checking out old commit

Tags: git

If

```
git log

#o/p

#commit 1

#commit 0
```

Then

```
git checkout 0
```

Then

```
git log

#commit 0
```

Commit 1 was erased...

I don't think this is normal behavior from my (limited) experience with git.  I am using it in dropBox, but it seems that that's ok.  Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: They're not gone! The issue is that `git log` starts by looking at the current, i.e., `HEAD`, commit, and working *back* from there (unless you give it some *other* starting point(s)). When you use `git checkout` to look back at an older commit, you won't see newer commits by default. Simply "re-attach your HEAD" as in sajib khan's answer to make `HEAD` refer to a branch name, so that `git log` starts from the current tip of that branch.

Comment: You have explicitly chosen to place your HEAD at commit 0 and hence this is the expected behavior. You HEAD is now pointing to commit 0. You could always execute 'git pull' and it HEAD will point to commit 1 (or latest)

Comment: All that said, you really should avoid keeping a repository under dropbox. Git and dropbox do not play well together.

Comment: Also, to make git log show all commits, use `git log --all`. If you lost the commit because there are no references to this commit, like branches or tags, use `git reflog` to see your previous git actions and checkout directly to the hash of the lost commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get back to the latest commit after checking out a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427288/how-to-get-back-to-the-latest-commit-after-checking-out-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit 1 wasn't erased in this case. You just switched to an older commit and now `git log` shows only commits that are ancestors to that [older] commit.

You can use `git checkout -` or `git checkout $commit1_hash` to return to a newer revision.

Also, it may be helpful to use [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to see history of switches between revisions.

Answer (score 1):

When we checkout to a commit-hash we are no longer on a branch (`detached HEAD`).

Checkout to branch. You should be back to your branch HEAD (exits commit0, commit1)

```
$ git branch                 # copy your branch name
$ git checkout <branch-name> # back to branch HEAD

Or,
$ git checkout -             # switch to the last commit you were
```

Comment: Is `git checkout -` equivalent to `git checkout master`?

Comment: No. `git checkout -` switch back to you wherever it was before the last checkout.