# How can I go back to the HEAD after `git checkout SHA`

Tags: git

I've just performed this action: `git checkout SHA` to look at the code of a past commit. I would now like to go back to how I had before (I presume this means go back to the HEAD) and carry on. How can I do this?

I tried `git log` to get the SHA for my most recent commit but it's not there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checkout, your `HEAD` is changed to the hash of the commit you selected. (The name `HEAD` refers to the most recent thing you checked out.) To change back to your `main` branch, use:

```
git checkout main
```

Use a different branch name if you want to switch back to a different branch.

Comment: Much appreciated. I now see this has been asked here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427288/how-to-get-back-to-the-latest-commit-after-checking-out-a-previous-commit

Comment: Thanks, I've added a duplicate link so other people can find the answer more quickly.